# Not able to extract whole text from an audio wav file. #Speech Recognition

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.WavFile("file.pcm.wav") as source:               
    audio = r.record(source)                       
try:
    print("Transcription: " + r.recognize_google(audio))   
except LookupError:                                
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

> > Output    (XYZ few words from the audio)**

Can someone explain what could be the reason for this. The audio file is good, it doesn't have any problem as its very clear and audible.

Answer (score 0):

The following information will help to diagnose this issue:

- How long is the `.wav` file in terms of duration (in seconds)?
- `speech_recognition` can be configured to use one of several speech recognition engines. Do you know which one you are using?
- Is the speech in English? And is it accented at all?
- Is the file definitely a `.wav` file and not a `.pcm` file named to be a `.wav` file?

Comment: 1. My file is 4:09 minutes long.

2. you mean version of speech_recognition?

3. Audio is in English, it has accent. 


4. It's a .pcm.wav file.

Comment: 1. Thanks. 4:09 is very very long for a speech recognition utterance. Use something like PyAudio to split your audio file up into much shorter lengths, ideally between 5-15 seconds. This is the length that most speech recognition engines are expecting.

2. Not the version, the speech recognition _engine_ - like Kaldi, Sphinx etc. Which one have you configured it to use? 

3. Accent _may_ be an issue here, but it's more likely to be utterance length.

4. Good to know, thanks for confirming - this doesn't sound like the issue.